# Return Selection as string in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, string

I create a lot of county boundaries and was wondering if I could turn a column into a string so I can drop it into another statistical package. In this case SAS and R. For example, the CNTYPROPER field

[image: screenshot of table]

would be returned as a string

("Sheriden","Mitchell")

Comment: Yes, sorry I should just do a screen shot. A character string is fine. I don't need another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run this within the Python window of ArcMap:

```
counties = str([str(row[0]) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("YourLayerName", ("CNTYPROPER"))])

cleaned = counties.replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")").replace("'", '"').replace(" ", "")

print cleaned
```

Comment: Awesome! I do have to do a bit of string manipulation it returns this ... [u'Sheriden', u'Mitchell',...] . Any tip there?

Comment: @DanKS I've updated my answer, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I played around and got it to work too. I used "print ', '.join(counties)", thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would do the manipulation directly in R.

```
require(rgdal)

# Read shapefile
shp = 'X:/path/to/your/shapefile.shp'
myshp = readOGR(shp, layer = basename(strsplit(shp, "\\.")[[1]])[1])

# Extract the attributes as a data frame
df = data.frame(myshp)

# Extract a specific field from data frame
field = df$CNTYPROPER
```

Comment: I'm going to totally use this method, I'd prefer something self contained for those who don't use R though. Thanks